# Software to Find Kernels/Co-Kernels of Boolean Expressions

Tags: boolean-algebra

Is there any (free) software available that calculates all the possible kernel/co-kernel pairs of a boolean expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A free tool is misII - Multiple-level Combinational Logic Optimization Program. It is contained in the Windows freeware package [Logic Friday 1](http://www.sontrak.com/) or in the Berkeley [Octtools](http://embedded.eecs.berkeley.edu/pubs/downloads/octtools/index.htm).

The terms `Kernel` and `Co-Kernel` are explained [here](http://www2.engr.arizona.edu/~ece571/articles/multilevelsyn.pdf).

**Edited:**

The misII documentation is available [online](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~david/courses/cs755/cs755/UCBtools/other/octtools/lib/misII/lib/help/print_kernel.fmt).

Interactive sample session with misII:

```
misII> read_eqn
z = (a+b+c)(d+e)f+g;
^Z
misII> print_kernel -as z
Subkernels of {z}
(a f + b f + c f) * (d + e)
(d f + e f) * (a + b + c)
misII> print_kernel -a z
Kernels of {z}
(a f) * (d + e)
(b f) * (d + e)
(c f) * (d + e)
(d f) * (a + b + c)
(e f) * (a + b + c)
(f) * (a d + a e + b d + b e + c d + c e)
(-1-) * (a d f + a e f + b d f + b e f + c d f + c e f + g)
```

Comment: I have Logic Friday - I don't believe it does kernel and co-kernel calculations. I haven't used Octtools, but I don't see any evidence on their website that it does this either. I'm not looking for logic optimization, but for one specific step of it.

Comment: Below the 'Logic Friday 1' installation directory there is a misII directory. Look into the misII help file to find out how the 'print kernels' operation works.

Comment: I take it back. Good work man.

Comment: Would you happen to know how to use the gkx function as well? I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: No, I don't have more information than source code and manual (page 13): http://www2.engr.arizona.edu/~veda/cadtools/sis/tutorials/sis.pdf   'gkx -?' gives a short help

Comment: The manual page is named "Page 50", but it is the 9th page in the file. See also http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~david/courses/cs755/cs755/UCBtools/other/octtools/lib/misII/lib/help/gkx.fmt